# MATLAB: Reshape every slice of a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, vectorization, reshape

Is it possible to reshape every slice of a 3D matrix using vectorization rather than the following for-loop-solution?

```
orig3D = rand(228,1,2);

for n = 1 : 2
    new3D(:,:,n) = reshape(orig3D(:,:,n), [12,19])';
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) -

```
new3D = permute(reshape(orig3D, 12,19,[]),[2,1,3])
```